# Storing New Line Characters in LDAP Attribute

Tags: attributes, ldap

How to store new Line Characters in an LDAP Attribute. I am stroring some data into a binary attribute. I have imported the Entry using LDIF which contains new Line characters. But when i export the Attribute LDIF it is showing all my new line characters as whitespaces.

Please let me know Am i Doing Some thing Wrong.

Regards,

Sunny.

Edited:

dn: erglobalid=0000000000000000323, ou=flows, ou=battle, ou=sunny, DC=pavan

erProName: proBooks

erXML:

```
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>

  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>

  <genre>Computer</genre>

  <price>44.95</price>

  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>

  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 

  with XML.</description>
```

erglobalid: 00000000000000000085

objectclass: top

objectclass: erflowDef

erCategory: Store

Comment: Can you paste the ldif file you have used, also what is the attribute type you have used?

Comment: The Content is XML Content. The Attribute type is 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.5

Comment: book tag's parent tag is <category> i can not edit it in the post...

Comment: and how are you exporting the attribute back? if its ldapsearch its going to print in hex format.

Comment: The ldap search returned as erXML:: PGNhdGVnb3J5PjxhdXRob3I+R2FtYmFyZGVsbGEsIE1hdHRoZXc8L2F1dGhvcj48dGl0bGU+WE1MIERldmVsb3BlcidzIEd1aWRlPC90aXRsZT48Z2VucmU+Q29tcHV0ZXI8L2dlbnJlPjxwcmljZT40NC45NTwvcHJpY2U+PHB1Ymxpc2hfZGF0ZT4yMDAwLTEwLTAxPC9wdWJsaXNoX2RhdGU+PGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPkFuIGluLWRlcHRoIGxvb2sgYXQgY3JlYXRpbmcgYXBwbGljYXRpb25zIHdpdGggWE1MLjwvZGVzY3JpcHRpb24+PC9jYXRlZ29yeT4gand decoding this using base64 decoder returns the xml, since its xml why do you need the newline character anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Investigating the Question should be how to store the new line characters in XML CDATA. I am able to figure out the issue. Sorry for asking Wrong Question. 
I found a question in another thread.